# Is there a list of browser support for various video formats?

Tags: video, browser

I was wondering which browsers and browser versions support which video formats? Can some one help me on this problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking which browsers codec support for the HTML5 `<video>` tag, the Wikipedia entry for [HTML5 Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) is fairly informative (taken 5th May 2013).

[image: Video Codec support in browsers (5th May 2013)]

It looks like Theora and VP8 are the most widely supported right now.

Answer (score 6):

##### Video formats:

- Internet Explorer 9+, Chrome 6+ and Safari 5+ can play MP4's (type="video/mp4")
- Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+ and Opera 10.6+ can play WebM's (type="video/webm")
- Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+ and Opera 10.6+ can play OGG's (type="video/ogg")

##### Audio formats:

- Internet Explorer 9+, Chrome 6+ and Safari 5+ can play MP3's (type="audio/mpeg")
- Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, Safari 5+ and Opera 10.6+ can play WAV's (type="audio/wav")
- Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+ and Opera 10.6+ can play OGG's (type="audio/ogg")

I wish there was at least one type of video & audio they all supported, and I wish they could all play .mid files and .avi files.