Why are some MP4 H264 videos not playable on Safari iPhone?
Note: Linked to MP4 video not playing on Safari iPhone.
In a blog post, I have a video embedded with <video><source src="..." that works for everyone (Firefox, Chrome, at least on PC / Linux / ...), but it specifically doesn't work on Safari iPhone.
Even if you access the video directly by its link on Safari iPhone, it doesn't work either: example: https://gget.it/io64/h264test13576.mp4
It only displays a gray background.
Any idea what it could be?
It has been encoded by OBS:
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 864x550 30fps 1989kbps [V: Video Media Handler (h264 high L3.1, yuv420p, 864x550, 1989 kb/s)]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz stereo 3kbps [A: Sound Media Handler [eng] (aac lc, 48000 Hz, stereo, 3 kb/s)]

OBS settings:


Mpeg4 is mostly just a container and it can contain various sorts of media inside it. Have you done any research to see the sorts of media that are compatible with Safari? Here's a question that asks for a list of compatible media types per browser that you may find helpful to solving this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/268597/is-there-a-list-of-browser-support-for-various-video-formats

@music2myear Yes MP4 is just a container, I mentioned the precise codecs in the question: H264 for video + AAC for audio. Both are supported by Safari. I have a beginning of answer: ffprobe test.mp4 gives: stream 0:0 audio, stream 0:1 video. If I recreate a new mp4 (without re-econding) with ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4 then it works in safari. The codecs are the same, the only difference is that, in out.mp4, we have: stream 0:0 video, stream 0:1 audio. Do you have an idea why it works in this case?
